# Service is not working?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, service, factory, controllers

So Here is a thing i want to pass Selected option from select list from one jsp page to another page using different controllers.

But i guess its not working and i dont want to use views or ngRoute

fileList.jsp

```
  <div ng-controller="fileController">
                    <form name="selectFile" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                <h4>Select a File<h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-offset-0">
                                <div class="form-group" >
                                    <select name="carrier_id" ng-model="selectedFile.serviceFile" ng-options="file[0] as file[1] for file in fileList" class="form-control">
                                     <option value=""> --Choose-- </option>
                                    </select>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                      <a href="${cp}/admin.jsp">Submit</a>                         </div>                   
                        <br/>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

admin.jsp

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
      {{id.serviceFile}}
</div>
```

admin.js

```
    var app = angular.module('admin', ['viewServices']); 
    app.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$rootScope', '$http', 'SelectedFile', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, SelectedFile) {   

        $scope.id = SelectedFile; 
    }]);  
app.controller('fileController', ['$scope','$rootScope', '$http','SelectedFile' , function($scope, $rootScope, $http, SelectedFile){

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url :'hrp/filelist' 
    }).success( function(data,status,headers,config){ 
        data.file_list.splice(0, 1) // to remove header row
        $scope.fileList=data.file_list
        $scope.selectedFile = SelectedFile;
       alert($scope.fileList)
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error")
    })  
}]);
```

service.js

```
    var viewServices = angular.module('viewServices', []);

viewServices.factory('SelectedFile', function() {
  return {
    serviceFile:''
  };
});
```

And all the scripts are included.
 So i just want that  mainController should return something in $scope.id

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data service

```
var viewServices = angular.module('viewServices', []);

viewServices.service('SelectedFile', function() {
    this.setData = function(data) {
        this.data = data;
    };
    this.getData = function() {
        return this.data;
    };
});
```

You can inject the service and use it.

Wherever you want to set data, use `viewServices.setData($scope.selectedFile)`

And in the next page wherever you wanna fetch this detail, just inject the same service in its controller and use `var something = viewServices.getData()`

Hope this helps